# How to change chapter created by \printindex to section?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, two-column, indexing

I wonder if there is a solution to the following problem: I wanted to create an index with the package `makeidx` and the `scrartcl` document class. `\printindex` creates a chapter called "Index". But all I wanted to have is a section (!) called "Index". (I cant find anything in the `makeidx` doc about this.) How can this be done? Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

    This is a test\index{test} text.

    \printindex % prints out a chapter but i want a section to be printed.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, `\printindex` *does* create an (unnumbered) `\section*` with the `article` and `scrartcl` classes -- but because the index uses `\twocolumn` internally, it starts on a new page, which does resemble `\chapter`s behaviour.

Solution: Load my [idxlayout](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) package -- it uses `multicol` internally and therefore does not start a new page. `idxlayout` is respondent to KOMA-Script's index-related options and commands.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

This is a test\index{test} text.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: tanks! this seems to point me in the right direction. but after compiling your source code with xelatex and processing with makeindex the output is just the same. do i have to do something else?

Comment: Delete all auxiliary files and then compile with `xelatex`-`makeindex`-`xelatex`- `xelatex`.

Comment: its working perfectly now! thx a lot!